# Microsoft Word Convert Field to Text VBA Code

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to convert Microsoft Word field codes to it's converted text.  Currently, I'm using a VBA code to convert numbers to written text, then I'm selecting selecting entire document contents, then Ctrl+Shift+F9 to convert.  Ideally I would be able to convert the numbers to text and remove fields in one shot.  Side note, my process is to Find all numbers which is done by Ctrl+F then ^#.  One by one, I convert numbers to text.  Would be nice if I could convert all once .  Also, for some reason when I convert the number it removes the space between the converted number's text and the next word -- would be nice if this didn't happen.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is the script I'm using to convert the numbers to text:

```
Sub ConvertNumberToWord()
'
' ConvertNumberToWord Macro
'
    Dim xDigit As Double
    Dim xBuff As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.MoveLeft wdWord, 1, wdMove
    Selection.MoveRight wdWord, 1, wdExtend
    xDigit = Val(Trim(Selection.Text))
    If xDigit = 0 And Str(xDigit) <> Trim(Selection.Text) Then Exit Sub
    If xDigit > 999999 Then
        If xDigit <= 999999999 Then
            xBuff = Trim(Int(Str(xDigit / 1000000)))
            Selection.Fields.Add Selection.Range, wdFieldEmpty, "= " + xBuff + " \* CardText" + " ", True
            Selection.MoveLeft wdWord, 1, wdExtend
            xBuff = Selection.Text & " million "
            xDigit = Right(Str(xDigit), 6)
        End If
    End If
    If xDigit <= 999999 Then
        Selection.Fields.Add Selection.Range, wdFieldEmpty, "= " + Str(xDigit) + " \* CardText" + " ", True
        Selection.MoveLeft wdWord, 1, wdExtend
        xDigit = xBuff & Selection.Text
        Selection.TypeText xDigit + " "
    Else
        MsgBox "Number too large", vbOKOnly, "Error Message"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So what's wrong with: ActiveDocument.Fields.Unlink?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by ActiveDocument.Fields.Unlink.

Comment: oh, lol! I see what you mean, simply add ActiveDocument.Fields.Unlink to script and it converts the number to text and removes field.  Thanks!